# Split the time & push object to array based on the consultation time - Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have array of object like this (Assume large array )

```
[
  {
    userID: '25634076cc1fccb0978ciug9f8f8b59cf7e6e0b0615d00de4df7e233bdb0d399',
    consultationTime: 4200 // in seconds
  },
  {
    userID: '48e69555d778f9b9a3a1d553b9c3b8f7dd6a3394ac82df1433b60a69c055d23d',
    consultationTime: 198741 // in seconds
  },
  {
    userID: 'a75d2f0a583b29ddba803af2a02ae1ee3b7b2c112fff8f41707aa9bb9aac9c90',
    consultationTime: 10 // in seconds
  }
];
```

Requirement:
I need to convert the consultationTime to minutes. Then if the consultationTime is less than 20 minutes then I need to push the consultationTime with code "11" to billingDetails. If consultationTime is greater than 20 minutes, then need to split the remaining time and push the time to code "22" as array of objects. remainingTime attribute will be calculated by subtracting with totalTime.

Example: For 4200 Seconds (70 minutes), first 20 minutes goes to code 11, remaining 50 minutes goes to code 22 as array of object with first object contains 20, next 20, next 10 as in the output.

Expected Output:

```
[
{
userID: '25634076cc1fccb0978ciug9f8f8b59cf7e6e0b0615d00de4df7e233bdb0d399',
billingDetails: [{
code: 11,
totalTime: 20 // first 20 minutes
remainingTime: 0 // 20 mins - totalTime
},
{
code: 22,
totalTime: 20
remainingTime: 0
},
{
code: 22,
totalTime: 20 
remainingTime: 0
},
{
code: 22,
totalTime: 10
remainingTime: 10 (20 minutes - 10 minutes)
}
]
},
{... similarly for other users},
];
```

I am having a hard time to deriving the logic for the same. So any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: It will be better if you specify the reason for down vote.

Comment: Not mine but I suspect that because you've shown no effort to solve this at all - essentially SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: @Jamiec Actually if somebody can point out the logic then i can try, but stuck on how to start.

Comment: How about converting seconds to minutes - Im sure you can do that bit. What else have you tried/researched regarding mapping (hint!) one array to the other?

Comment: @Jamiec yeah converting seconds to minutes I can do that. the point where I am stuck is not sure how to split the time with 20 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over the time and remove a "time period" from the consultationTime until there is non left. Then with [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) you can create a new object for the end result.

```js
const data = [
  {
    userID: '25634076cc1fccb0978ciug9f8f8b59cf7e6e0b0615d00de4df7e233bdb0d399',
    consultationTime: 4200 // in seconds
  },
  {
    userID: '48e69555d778f9b9a3a1d553b9c3b8f7dd6a3394ac82df1433b60a69c055d23d',
    consultationTime: 198741 // in seconds
  },
  {
    userID: 'a75d2f0a583b29ddba803af2a02ae1ee3b7b2c112fff8f41707aa9bb9aac9c90',
    consultationTime: 10 // in seconds
  }
];

const getBillingDetails = (seconds, size) => {
  let minutes = seconds / 60;
  let first = true;
  const details = [];
  
  while(minutes > 0) {
    const haveEnough = minutes >= size;
    
    details.push({
      code: first ? 11 : 22,
      totalTime: haveEnough ? size : minutes,
      remainingTime: haveEnough ? 0 : size - minutes,
    })
    
    minutes -= size;
    first = false;
  }
  
  return details;
}

const consultationTimeToBillingDetails = (data, size) => {
  return data.map(({consultationTime, ...rest}) => {
    return {
      ...rest,
      billingDetails: getBillingDetails(consultationTime, size)
    }
  });
}

const result = consultationTimeToBillingDetails(data, 20);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

**Explanation**

```js
const data = [
  {
    userID: '25634076cc1fccb0978ciug9f8f8b59cf7e6e0b0615d00de4df7e233bdb0d399',
    consultationTime: 4200 // in seconds
  },
  {
    userID: '48e69555d778f9b9a3a1d553b9c3b8f7dd6a3394ac82df1433b60a69c055d23d',
    consultationTime: 198741 // in seconds
  },
  {
    userID: 'a75d2f0a583b29ddba803af2a02ae1ee3b7b2c112fff8f41707aa9bb9aac9c90',
    consultationTime: 10 // in seconds
  }
];

const getBillingDetails = (seconds, size) => {
  // Turn seconds into minutes
  let minutes = seconds / 60;
  // Boolean to check if it is the first iteration since it has a different code
  let first = true;
  // Array to push objects into
  const details = [];
  
  // If we still have minutes left, execute the while block
  while(minutes > 0) {
    // Boolean to check if we have atleast 20 minutes left
    const haveEnough = minutes >= size;
    
    details.push({
      code: first ? 11 : 22, // Set code to 11 on first iteration all the others have code 22
      totalTime: haveEnough ? size : minutes, // If we have atleast 20 minutes set that as totalTime else set it as the remaining minutes
      remainingTime: haveEnough ? 0 : size - minutes, // If we have atleast 20 minutes set the remaingTime to 0 else calculate the missing time.
    })
    
    // Remove 20 minutes before we start the while loop again
    minutes -= size;
    // Set boolean to false since we finished our first iteration
    first = false;
  }
  
  // Return all the details once the while loop is over
  return details;
}

const consultationTimeToBillingDetails = (data, size) => {
  // Return mapped data
  return data.map(({consultationTime, ...rest}) => {
    return {
      // Spread other properties since we need them on the new object
      ...rest,
      // Get billing details from consultationTime and size
      billingDetails: getBillingDetails(consultationTime, size)
    }
  });
}

// Get billing details from data and specify size to split by
const result = consultationTimeToBillingDetails(data, 20);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you please explain const haveEnough = minutes >= size; a bit?

Comment: It wil just resolve into a boolean, we pass 20 as the chunks (size) of minutes we want. Then we check if we have 20 or more minutes left. If we do the variable becomes true if not it becomes false (you can check this by logging the variable). I use it for my [ternary operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) a few lines down. (ternary is just a smaller if else statement)

Comment: @DEEPESHKUMARR I added an extra snippet with some comments to explain how to code works. PS: if it works i would appreciate an upvote and checkmark for correct answer

Answer (score 1):

```js
const inputArray = [
  {
    userID: "25634076cc1fccb0978ciug9f8f8b59cf7e6e0b0615d00de4df7e233bdb0d399",
    consultationTime: 4200,
  },
  {
    userID: "48e69555d778f9b9a3a1d553b9c3b8f7dd6a3394ac82df1433b60a69c055d23d",
    consultationTime: 198741,
  },
  {
    userID: "a75d2f0a583b29ddba803af2a02ae1ee3b7b2c112fff8f41707aa9bb9aac9c90",
    consultationTime: 10,
  },
];

function splitTimeAndPush(inputArray) {
  let outputArray = [];
  inputArray.forEach((element) => {
    let output = { userId: element.userID, billingDetails: [] };
    let minutes = element.consultationTime / 60; // consultaionTime in minutes
    for (let i = 0; i < minutes; i += 20) {
      let bD = { code: "", totalTime: "", remainingTime: "" };
      if (i === 0) {
        bD.code = 11;
      } else {
        bD.code = 22;
      }
      bD.totalTime = minutes - i > 20 ? 20 : minutes - i;
      bD.remainingTime = 20 - bD.totalTime;
      output.billingDetails.push(bD);
    }
    outputArray.push(output);
  });
  return outputArray;
}

const sp = splitTimeAndPush(inputArray);
console.log(sp);
```